# Should I overload sin(x) from more standard math library or do I develop my own class method sin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, overriding

I need to write an "automatic differentiation" module where the standard `sin(x)`, `cos(x)`, `exp(x)` needs to be overloaded to include additional calculation regarding derivative. For "+,-,/", I simply used the Dunder method such as `__add__`, etc. But what about `sin(x)`, `cos(x)`, `exp(x)`? Is it better to define my own methods (based off of `math.sin(x)` etc.) or somehow overload these like I did with +,-,/. If the latter is better, how should I do it?

Comment: FWIW, I think it's a reasonable question and not really opinion-based.

Comment: IMO whenever you want to know if something is "better" than something else, you need to be very specific about what you mean by the term — in other words in what sense.

Answer (score 1):

Define your own. If another app imported your package and then found out that `sin()` wasn’t what it expected, things could explode. In general, in Python it’s very frowned upon to “monkey patch” libraries.